# VS 2013 opens the diff window when a code review item is marked as done

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-code-review

My team uses TFS 2013/Visual Studio 2013 to do code reviews. It all works fine but there is a really annoying thing which VS does that I can't seem to turn off.

If I submit a review and it comes back with suggested changes, I go through and make them, checking each one off as I go. The problem is each time I mark a code review item as done by checking the box to the far right of it in the Team Explorer -> Code Review view, VS opens the diff window for that particular item showing the review comments. I don't want to see any of that, I just want to mark the item as done so I know I've dealt with it.

Is there any way to prevent VS from showing the diff window when you mark a code review item as done?